# Is there a way to tell pylint not to warn on redefined-outer-name for functions?

Tags: python, pylint

Is there a way to shut pylint up about re-using the same variable name in a function call, but have it complain when I mistakenly re-use the same variable in a sub-scope within a function?

For example, this is completely legitimate:

```
def fun(avar):
    return str(avar + 1)

avar = 1
print(fun(avar))
```

But I would like to be warned if I:

```
i = 1
for i in range(10):
    print(str(i))
```

For example.

Comment: If you pylint some code that has both of those cases, does pylint return two different diagnostic codes?  If so, then yes, you can tell pylint to ignore one but not the other.

Comment: That's a good question; let me test.

Comment: It does not.  It doesn't even detect the second case, lol